# Inverse Feature Scaling not working while predicting results

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning

```
# Importing required libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Importing dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1: -1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values

y = y.reshape(len(y), 1)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scy = StandardScaler()
scX = StandardScaler()
X = scX.fit_transform(X)
y = scy.fit_transform(y)

# Training SVR model
from sklearn.svm import SVR
regressor = SVR(kernel = 'rbf')
regressor.fit(X, y)

# Predicting results from SCR model
# this line is generating error
scy.inverse_transform(regressor.predict(scX.transform([[6.5]])))
```

I am trying to execute this code to predict values from the model but after running it I am getting errors like this:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[-0.27861589].
Reshape your data either using an array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Complete Stack trace of error:
[image: Stack Trace of Error]

Even my instructor is using the same code but his one is working mine one not I am new to machine learning can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here.
Thanks for your help.
This is the data for reference
[image: Position_Salaries.csv]

Comment: please elaborate on the shape of the dataset

Comment: Also, please add the complete erorr trace. Its not clear which line of code is actually throwing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the shape of your predictions, the `scy` is expecting an output with `(-1, 1)` shape.
 Change your last line to this:

```
scy.inverse_transform([regressor.predict(scX.transform([[6.5]]))])
```

You can also use this line to predict:

```
pred = regressor.predict(scX.transform([[6.5]]))
pred = pred.reshape(-1, 1)
scy.inverse_transform(pred)
```

Comment: But my instructor used the same code for him it run successfully and when I ran it threw error can u explain me why it is happening.

Comment: No, the code you mentioned can't run, regardless of versions. There might be some mistakes in copy-pasting.